# NoSuchMethodError in bouncycastle

Tags: android, cryptography, bouncycastle, nosuchmethoderror

To use crypto in Android I tried Bouncy Castle provider, the latest version 1.4.9. When trying code from https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1527913?start=15&tstart=0, the error occured:

```
11-22 11:05:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(443): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 11:05:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(443): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair.getPublic
```

I dont know why the first time it succeeded but failed afterwards, no matter whether I restart the Eclipse/System. It's very weird.

Kindest regards.

Comment: Please post your activity code and full logcat logs.

Comment: It's just a simple Android project from the wizard, you can create it yourself in the Eclipse. I am using the latest ADT Bundle adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030.

If not a problem of configuration, I think maybe it's about provider confliction: Android has built-in BC security provider(the app runs on), and I added the latest Bouncy Castle provider explicitly(the app compiles on). They have the different version numbers, which causes NoSuchMethodError.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Spongycastle](http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/) or [jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/wiki/GettingStarted) your own Bouncycastle library. Android does include a copy of Bouncycastle, but you should use your own copy in an app. Honeycomb (API 11) and later moved its copy of the library under the package "com.android.org.bouncycastle," but earlier Android versions will conflict with your app's copy.

Comment: I've asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155285/does-an-android-cryptography-provider-need-to-be-signed) if a provider needs to be signed to be able to use it within Android. If you know, could you answer that? If the `.jar` needs to be signed, then using `jarjar` would probably not work - at least not without a key.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I gave an expanded answer in your other question.

Comment: Nice, "unfortunately" I had already +1'ed you, but I guess the other answer will let you receive a few +1's and likely an accept :)

Comment: Great, kroot, it works great on Android. Nevertheless, as the example code shows, different providers yield different encrypted texts. And my app will communicate encrypted text with app server, which needs to encrypt/decrypt texts from my app, so, does Spongy Castle have a counterpart in app server(for example, in Tomcat, not in Android)? Is it still Bouncy Castle? Are they two(Spongy Castle in Android app, Bouncy Castle in Tomcat server) compatible(i.e., one end can decrypt text from the other end)?

Comment: Append to last comment: That **different providers yield different encrypted texts** doesnt always hold true. But my question still needs your confirmation/advice:)

Comment: They won't yield different encrypted texts if you're explicit in how you use the APIs. For instance, specify fully "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", set your IvParameterSpec with output from SecureRandom#nextBytes, etc.