# Does an android cryptography provider need to be signed?

Tags: android, security, cryptography

In Java SE from Oracle, it is required for a provider of cryptographic functions to be signed. This signing needs to occur using a private key belonging to a certificate that has been signed by Oracle. If the `.jar` of the provider is not signed, then the provider cannot be plugged into the Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA) as a Java Cryptography Extension (JCE).

Does Android 4.0-4.4 require the providers to be signed as well? If so, are there specific regulations to creating a key/certificate pair that is used for signing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. Your application is the only thing running in the Android sandbox, so the SecurityManager interface doesn't make any sense. As a caveat, you shouldn't load and run untrusted code (see the [Android docs on SecurityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/SecurityManager.html))